# How do I print a full list where a user has input a name from that list? PYTHON

Tags: python, list

I've been able to find plenty of info on selecting a value from the list, but I want to select a list from the value contained within it. The issue is I don't want it to be as long-winded as doing a bunch of '*if*'s as that's overkill.

Is there a way to use the value to print the entire list? This is to help me in computing lessons later down the line. I should already know this from previous years, though due to the nature of my course, my peers may not.

This is the relevant code:

```
Doggo_Database = [['Lilly', 'Jack Russell', 'White', 'F', 2009, 'Medium'],
                  ['Winston', 'Pug', 'Brown', 'M', 2010, 'Small'],
                  ['Bo', 'Doberman', 'Brown', 'M', 2011, 'Large'],
                  ['Shep', 'Border Collie', 'Black', 'M', 2006, 'Large'],
                  ['Rodney', 'Jack Russell', 'Grey', 'F', 2010, 'Medium'],
                  ['Butch', 'Bulldog', 'White', 'F', 2011, 'Medium'],
                  ['Sally', 'Boston Terrier', 'Brown', 'F', 2013, 'Small']]
names = [Doggo_Database[0][0], Doggo_Database[1][0], Doggo_Database[2][0], Doggo_Database[3][0], Doggo_Database[4][0], Doggo_Database[5][0], Doggo_Database[6][0]]
name_select = input('Do you know the name of the Doggo? If yes, state the name. If no, state NO in capital letters. ')
while name_select != 'NO' and name_select not in names:
    print('This is not a valid entry.')
    name_select = input('Please try again: ')
    
if name_select != 'NO':
    for name in names:
        if name_select == name:
            print(name_select)
            Data_name = 
elif name_select == 'NO':
    print("We're currenly unable to find the doggo until more search options are availble")
else:
    print('a logic error has occurred')
```

I'm using base python for this, not SQL

Comment: `Data_name = ` will make your code snippet won't work

Answer (score 0):

I gues that you are looking for the `Data_name =` respective list
Given the way that your code is written you can do this:

```
Data_name = [i for i in Doggo_Database if i[0]==name_select][0]
```

For example if `name_select = 'Bo'`

result will be

```
['Bo', 'Doberman', 'Brown', 'M', 2011, 'Large']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use python [dict](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) (as the dogs DB) it will make your code much cleaner.

```
db = {'Lilly': ['Jack Russell', 'White', 'F', 2009, 'Medium'],
      'Winston': ['Pug', 'Brown', 'M', 2010, 'Small']}

name_select = input('Do you know the name of the Doggo? If yes, state the name. If no, state NO in capital letters. ')
while name_select != 'NO' and name_select not in db:
    print('This is not a valid entry.')
    name_select = input('Please try again: ')

if name_select != 'NO':
    print(f'Dog details: {db.get(name_select)}')
else:
    print("We're currenly unable to find the doggo until more search options are availble")
```